# Find centers of circular clusters in a point cloud

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, cluster-analysis

I need to find a solution for the following problem. I want to find the centers of circular clusters within a point cloud. For example, in the bottom picture i want to identify 3 centers. I was trying to use clustering algorithms (e.g.,kmeans, kmedians, gaussian mixture models) to find the centers of the clusters, but they did not give proper results without individual parametrization(e.g. number of clusters).

Does anyone has a suggestion which methods can be used for solving this problem?

[image: point cloud data]

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of choices.

- Gaussian Mixture Modeling, with a heuristic to optimize the parameters
- DBSCAN, with postprocessing to compute cluster centers
- OPTICS, with postprocessing to compute cluster centers
- Mean-Shift, the most dense points are your centers.
- many
- many
- many
- more